# Difference between > and | with /dev/tty

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe

When I run this command:

```
echo "1" > /dev/tty # runs successfully
```

but when I run this:

```
echo "1" | /dev/tty #permission denied
```

What is the difference between these two operators `>` and `|` and why does the pipe cause an error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer:** `>` must be followed by a filename or `&n` (n is a number), and `|` must be followed by another command invocation.

---

**Details:** In shell syntax, a call to some command contains several components. Example:

```
A=foo 2>/dev/null B=bar cmd arg1 arg2 >file 3>&4 arg3
```

Here, parameters `2>/dev/null`, `>file` and `3>&4` are special parameters (containing an unescaped `>`¹), they are used to establish io-redirections, and can appear anywhere  in the command line. Filedesciptor 2 is redirected to `/dev/null`, filedescriptor `1` (implicit) is redirected to `file` and filedescriptor `3` is redirected to what filedescriptor 4 was linked to.

Then, among remaining parameters, `A=foo` and `B=bar` contain `=`, so they are not considered as the command name: they give specific values to environment variables of the process to be launched.

Then comes the command `cmd` and the real arguments: `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`.

The pipe `|` is not part of a command invocation, it links two such invocations together. Example:

```
CC=gcc make 2>&1 | LESS=--quit-at-eof less
```

Output on filedescriptor 1 by the first process will be received as input on filedescriptor 0 by the second process, through a “pipe” which acts like a buffer.

—
<sup>1. In fact, the special characters like `>` are sometimes seen followed by a space. Even though this is allowed, the two (space-separated) strings must be understood as a single ‘entity’.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

The `|` is used to pipe data between processes while `>` is used to redirect a stream to a file. `/dev/tty` is a "file"/device owned by root and its permissions are set to 666 as a result when you try to pipe to it your shell attempts to execute /dev/tty to stream data to it and it doesn't have execute permissions.